# Confused about VLANs with regards to Wireless network

Tags: networking, wifi-configuration, vlan

I am using this as my main router: `TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND v1`
I am using this firmware on my main router: `LEDE Reboot 17.01.4 r3560-79f57e422d / LuCI lede-17.01 branch (git-19.055.62634-0cc62b4)`
I am using this as my AP: `Netgear Nighthawk R7000`
I am using this firmware on my AP: `V1.0.9.18_1.2.27 (stock firmware)`

I want to add a guest wifi to my AP, and separate it from my private network with VLANs and subnetting. I know I can't do this with my APs stock firmware, so I am thinking of installing dd-wrt on it, as OpenWrt/LEDE doesn't seem to be compatible.

Specifically: I want to create multiple SSIDs, each associated with a unique VLAN, that I can trunk between my AP and my main router.

My problem is that I can't find any digestible information regarding how I would associate wireless devices with VLANs, and how/if I can create virtual wireless interfaces.

As I understand it, I'd have to first create a VLAN interface on the switch (let's call it eth0.3, and let's also say, eth0.1 => Port 1 => main router). I'd then have to create a bridge interface with eth0.3 and eth0.1 (let's call this br0). And then I'd have to create a virtual interface on the wlan device(?), and bridge this to br0?

I'd like to know whether or not this is correct, and if it isn't, I'd be grateful if someone would please clarify this subject. I am sorry if I've got something fundamentally wrong, as I'm new to VLANs in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to remember is that VLAN packets are just normal packets with an additional field that contains the number of the VLAN.

In this way, one can have multiple different network structures on the same hardware infrastructure. To visualize this, draw a picture of your network hardware infrastructure, then take two different colors and draw your "guest" network in one color, and your "private" network in another color.
Each of those networks will end in a different AP.

If you look at this picture, some computers in the network will be part of both networks, some of only one. You may need to "transfer" from one network into the other network at some points (possibly with a firewall in between). In some places it may be more convenient to route to an untagged network (no VLAN). Etc., etc.

This diagram will describe how you'll have to implement your VLANs. Every computer that takes part in both networks will need VLAN network interfaces for each (`eth0.1` and `eth0.3`, or `wlan0.1` and `wlan0.3`, etc.). Every computer that only takes part in a single "colored" network will only need one of these. Every computer that "transfers" will need to bridge or route between those. Etc.

And without knowing this diagram (which is specific to your home network) we can't tell you in detail what to put where, or make suggestions how to improve it. In particular "you'll always create VLAN interfaces on the switch, and bridge it with something else" is the wrong way to go about it. The network design comes first.